# Decode variables in PHP

Tags: php, magento, server

I wrote this function to create new account in magento, but if I write arabic words, it send encoded data and the data is sended with url encoded so I want to decode it. And it create the account with encoded data like this

```
%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF %D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B1
```

the original words `[ محمد صابر ]`

```
function register($email , $password , $firstname , $lastname  )
{
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
if(!$customer->getId()) {
    $customer->setEmail(utf8_decode($email));
    $customer->setFirstname(utf8_decode($firstname));
    $customer->setLastname(utf8_decode($lastname));
    $customer->setPassword(utf8_decode($password));

    try {
    $customer->save();
    $customer->setConfirmation(null);
    $response["success"] = 1;

}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
}

}
else{
$response["success"] = 0;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
return json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Change form method to `POST`, it's better as you send more than just small texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
$decodedString = urldecode($endodedString);
```